# Bitcoin sent from one wallet to another didn't reach

Tags: blockchain, wallet, exchanges, protocol

looking for some help and advice here.

I sent 2.27 BTC from one exchange (Coinsecure) to another (Koinex). However, the receiving exchange (Koinex) only credited 0.327 to my wallet. I have been trying to figure out what happened to the remaining ~1.94, and it appears from blockchain, that these were sent out from my wallet to another address. However, in my Koinex account, I see neither a deposit nor a withdrawal.

All the transactions are in this link:
https://blockchain.info/address/15Rvzpv3L4FTMxoVfxqWHrqu9UKzFEo3gy

What do you think might be going on here? How can Koinex not recognise the receipt and allow the withdrawal without my knowledge or authorisation?

Looking for help from the wonderful experts here, along with suggestions on what I could do. Have tried all the channels to reach out to Koinex (tweets, emails, support requests, Facebook messages), but in vain.

Comment: It might be helpful if you include some screenshots from both Coinsecure and Koinex to let us know what they are showing you about these transfers.

Comment: Hi Eric, thanks for your comment. After persistent follow-up with Koinex they final responded, investigated and credited me the missing BTCs.